# Are there scriptural citations denigrating eating during war?

Tags: scripture, reference-request

During Mahabharata Yuddha Kanda, there don't seem to be many verses depicting that Krishna ate food.

Are there scriptural verses putting down eating during war ?

Comment: Without eating how can the warriors fight? Where did u get this idea from? Also did the text mention Krishna going to toilets or bathing during that period? If not will u assume that those acts too shd not be done during war ?

Comment: Nice sarcastic question similar to the others we are seeing nowadays :)

Comment: Oh is it so? what sarcasm is in this one? I didn't get any @user1952500

Comment: Some things such as: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32650/are-there-scriptural-citations-denigrating-old-age and a few others I think that may have been closed / removed.

Comment: Mahābhārata war usually only documents the war that was fought during the day. It doesn't share many other details that happened throughout the rest of the time, within the dwellings of the opposing parties, such as consumption of refreshments, etc. Just because this information isn't mentioned, doesn't imply that the participating warriors stayed hungry and didn't eat any food. You never see mention of Arjuna chewing toothwood in Mahābhārata or Yudhiṣṭhira bathing, but that doesn't imply that both didn't do so in the morning.

Comment: @Bingming - it was a sarcastic question made in response to other questions seen on the site at that time